# Trying to align image on the right of text using HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my image next to the text using HTML, so far I have tried adding float:right but it just seems to push the div down. I have also tried adding overflow:hidden but it does not seem to work.

I am using media queries to make this website responsive, and this is where I am having issues with moving the image to the right of the text,

I hope you can help.

```
<section id="section_about" class="grid">
            <h2 class="content-title">
                Our Story
            </h2>
        <div class="content-wrap about_content">
            <p>
                The History of Kitchens and Cooks gives further intimation on Mr Boulanger usual menu, stating
                confidently that "Boulanger served salted poultry and fresh eggs, all presented without a tablecloth
                on small marble tables". Numerous commentators have also referred to the supposed restaurant owner's
                eccentric habit of touting for custom outside his establishment, dressed in aristocratic fashion and
                brandishing a sword
                <br><br>
                Numerous commentators have also referred to the supposed restaurant owner's eccentric habit of
                touting for custom outside his establishment, dressed in aristocratic fashion and brandishing a
                sword
            </p>
            
        </div>

        <div class="about_img_container">
            <img src="./img/about_img.jpg" class="about_img">
        </div>
        
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
 .content-title {

font-family: 'Playball', sans-serif;
color: #C59D5F;
font-size: 2.5em;
padding: 5px 0;
margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .content-wrap p {

padding-left: 20px;
line-height: 30px;
 }

 .about_img{

padding: 0 10px;
 }

 @media(min-width: 1024px) {
.about_content {

    width: 50%;
    background: pink;
}

.about_img_container{
   background: red;
   margin: 150px;
   float: right;
   overflow: hidden;
}
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Make content float left instead ;) and see what you can do from here

Comment: @G-Cyrillus does not seem to work

Comment: hello, with float, the way is to float the first element, so the next might stand aside : https://jsfiddle.net/4e1yt50r/ but today, grid is plenty efficient to keep float for other purposes : grid : https://jsfiddle.net/4e1yt50r/1/ . have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more **modern** way of doing this would be with **flexbox**:

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="content-wrap about_content">
        <p>
            Your Text here
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="about_img_container">
        <p>sodfosdf</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

The **justify-content** property defines how the two elements are displayed next to each other or under each other.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to remove h2 from the section:

```
    <h2 class="content-title">
           Our Story
    </h2>

<section id="section_about" class="grid">
        <div class="content-wrap about_content">
            <p>
                The History of Kitchens and Cooks gives further intimation on Mr Boulanger usual menu, stating
                confidently that "Boulanger served salted poultry and fresh eggs, all presented without a tablecloth
                on small marble tables". Numerous commentators have also referred to the supposed restaurant owner's
                eccentric habit of touting for custom outside his establishment, dressed in aristocratic fashion and
                brandishing a sword
                <br><br>
                Numerous commentators have also referred to the supposed restaurant owner's eccentric habit of
                touting for custom outside his establishment, dressed in aristocratic fashion and brandishing a
                sword
            </p>
            
        </div>

        <div class="about_img_container">
            <img src="./img/about_img.jpg" class="about_img">
        </div>
        
    </section>
```

Then give the section a display: flex.

```
#section_about {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just restrict the size of the image container by applying an appropriate `width` to it in your CSS rule, and move it *above* the DIV that contains the text so the text can float next to and under the image.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-wrap about_content">
        <p>
            Pls text here
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="about">
        <p>Pls text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```